# Error Segmentation Fault - Why does my code keep calling my Recursive function infinitely?

Tags: c, sorting, recursion

Aim : Arranging negative elements of an array on L.H.S and positive Elements on  R.H.S

Using : Recursion

Datatype used : I have used Array but it is inside a structure i.e. Array ADT

Error : Segmentation Fault

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct Array 
{
    int a[10];
    int len;
};

void swap(int *a,int *b)
{
    int temp;
    temp = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = temp;
}

void NegativeSort(struct Array *arr, int i, int j)
{

    if(i < j)
    {
    
        if(arr-> a[i] > 0 && arr-> a[j] <= 0)
        {
            swap(&arr-> a[i], &arr-> a[j]);
            NegativeSort(arr, i++, j--);
        }
    
        else if(arr-> a[i] >= 0)
            NegativeSort(arr, i, j--);
    
        else
            NegativeSort(arr, i++, j);
    }
}


int main()
{
    struct Array arr = {{-1,2,-3,4,-5,6,-7,8},8};
           
    NegativeSort(&arr, 0, 7);
    
    printf("elements are : ");
    for(i = 0; i < arr.len - 1; i++)
        printf("%d", arr.a[i]);
    
    return 0;
    
}
```

Comment: 1) Your struct array has 8 "valid" elements: `arr->a[0]` to `arr->a[7]`. You try to access `arr->a[8]` which is `0`.

Comment: Noted. But even if you put `NegativeSort(&arr,0,1)` as argument, it still gives segmentation fault error.

Comment: Fix that error... access elements from `i` to `j-1`. I suspect it's related to your infinite recursion.

Comment: What is the point of the post-increment and -decrement in the recursive function? The `i` and `j` are not used again so it does not do anything useful. Did you mean to inc/dec some other values, or to pre-inc/dec? As it stands, `i` and `j` are passed to the recursion unchanged, i.e. it always recurses effectively as `NegativeSort(arr, i, j);` Perhaps `NegativeSort(arr, i, j--);` was meant to be `NegativeSort(arr, i, j-1);` etc.

Comment: ...if `(i < j)` is true at the start of the first function call, it will always be true therefore infinite recursion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's your use if post increment and decrement operators in the recursive calls of NegativeSort. You call NegativeSort(arr,0,7) from main. If that calls NegativeSort(arr, i, j--); then the arguments to that call will be (arr,0,7) again, because the value of j-- is the same as j. It would be better to call NegativeSort(arr, i, j-1); and similarly for NegativeSort(arr, i++, j), it shpold be NegativeSort(arr, i+1, j)